# Are cheap cable remotes for the iPhone and iPad good for listening to podcasts

Tags: iphone, ipod, podcasts, remote-control

I like to listen to podcasts while driving - but I can't use the iPhone's touch interface to play/pause podcasts because it requires looking at the iPhone long enough to cause an accident.

I'm looking for a physical pause/play button I can operate by touch and I've found this product on eBay [Cable Remote Music Control for Apple iPod Nano 6 Touch 3 Classic iPhone 4S 4 3GS](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Cable-Remote-Music-Control-for-Apple-iPod-Nano-6-Touch-3-Classic-iPhone-4S-4-3GS-/190589731872?pt=Other_MP3_Player_Accessories&hash=item2c60088420)

I've had issues before with a car's built-in iPod control that would mark a podcast as completely played even if I listened only to a short part of it and that made that car's iPod control completely useless for me.

Does anyone here has experience with that iPhone remote and knows if it works well for podcasts?

Recommendation for alternative products are also welcome, as long as the alternative is cheap

if it makes any difference the iPhone is connected to the car's radio speakers with a cable connected to the phone's earphones jack.

Comment: The remote looks really nice but I find myself more in need of "go back 30 seconds" then start/stop. That is something I really miss while listening with headphones.

Comment: @Hoshts - I think I've never used the "go back 30 seconds" option, probably because I never listen when it's convenient to operate the iPhone. I need start/stop all the time because I use it when I'm getting phone calls while driving, I listen to podcasts on my iPhone but I get calls to a dedicated car phone, so I need to pause the iPhone every time I get a phone call and un-pause when the call is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bought one and after using it for 2 days I can say it works just fine.

Note: every time you disconnect it and reconnect it to the iPhone it forget the volume (and starts on very low, impossible to hear volume level) and it does pick up some interference (probably from the phone) every one in a while - but it solves my problem and it's a very good buy for $5.50

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue, and here's the workaround I use:

**I create a playlist and add the podcasts I want to listen to that day.**

It's a little time consuming but then I do not have to try and find the podcast on my ipod while driving.